# Get Roblox installed with wine out of my desktop

Tags: games, .desktop

I installed Roblox with Wine on Ubuntu, but it went to my desktop with 2 .link files, and the Roblox Studio.desktop file and Roblox Player.desktop file. This is horribly disorganized, I tried moving them but they only work on my desktop, it's incredibly annoying. How do I make a file that can start it from my games folder instead?

Comment: If you provide information about where on your system Roblox is installed, I can tell you how I would do it. For the games I use wine to play, basically I write a script to start the game, and then I make a desktop entry for the script.